# AngularJS testing directives with Karma, Jasmine and ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: template not loaded

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm testing a custom AngularJS directive using Karma + Jasmine and the `ngHtml2JsPreprocessor` plugin in order to serve my directive template, but I don't understand why my directive seems to be unable to access to the template (the compiled element is empty).
I defined the `templateUrl` in the directive this way:

```
templateUrl: 'templates/angular/mywidget.html'
```

my Karma config is the following (the relevant part of it):

```
        basePath: '../../main/webapp/static/',
        files: [
            {pattern: 'libs/angular/angular.js', watch: false},
            {pattern: 'libs/angular-resource/angular-resource.js', watch: false},
            {pattern: 'libs/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', watch: false},
            {pattern: 'libs/angular-ngkit/js/ngkit.js', watch: false},
            {pattern: 'libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js', watch: false},
            'templates/angular/*.html',
            'js/angular/**/*.js',
            '../../../test/js/spec/angular/*.js'
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            'templates/angular/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
        },
        ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
            moduleName: 'templates'
        },
        browsers: [
            'PhantomJS'
        ],
        plugins: [
            'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor'
        ],
```

and in my test:

```
beforeEach(module('templates'));
beforeEach(module('ngResource'));
beforeEach(module('mywidget'));
```

the "funny" part is that if I test the template cache, the templates gets loaded and compiled:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$templateCache_) {
    var template = _$templateCache_.get('templates/angular/mywidget.html');
}));
```

template exists! Why my directive can't use it? (in the browser it works perfectly).
If I replace `templateUrl` with an inline `template` in my directive, it gets rendered properly in the test... but I have to use an external template, is not acceptable to put it inline... I'm stuck!! Any smart idea?

**UPDATE (what I've tried so far):**

1. write a new directive with no logic (to exclude that the problem was in the implementation), simply:

   `angular.module('modulename', []).
       directive('foo', function() {
           return {
               templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html'
           }
       });`
2. simplify the template content to:

   `<div>hello world</div>`
3. change the template path
4. change the template name
5. change the location of karma config file
6. removes extra dependencies like "ngResource" and similar
7. reinstalling all the bower dependencies (and cleaning the cache)
8. reinstalling all the npm packages
9. run tests from the command line (I was running test in Intellij Idea using the Karma plugin)
10. Pounding my fists against the desk while throwing a Fibonacci sequences of blasphemies that would have killed the pope if he had listened to it!

(the latest one usually brings me to the solution... but not this time)

**UPDATE 2:**

I bypassed the problem by defining my directive in this way:

```
directive('mywidget', function($templateCache) {
        var config = {}; // directive definition (where you define "link", "restrict"...)
        var templateUrl = 'templates/angular/mywidget.html';
        var cachedTemplate = $templateCache.get(templateUrl);
        if (cache) {
            config.template = cachedTemplate;
        }
        else {
            config.templateUrl = templateUrl;
        }
        return config;
});
```

By using this trick, my directive get rendered properly in tests.
A this point it sounds a bug in AngularJS... it fails somehow to load the template from the cache.
I'm really disappointed :(

Comment: I had the same issue, but in my case the fix was simple: call `scope.$apply()` after calling `$compile()`, otherwise the template doesn't have a chance to be loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YEAAAAAAAAAAH!!!
I finally solved this crazy issue!!!
The problem was that I was using different versions of angular dependecies (angular-mocks, angular-resource...) it turned out that If you are using, let's say, angular 1.2.27, then you **MUST** also be sure to use angular-mocks 1.2.27, angular-resource 1.2.27 and so on because otherwise there may be conflicts like the one I faced.
Of course it wasn't my intention to use different versions, but somehow by installing my dependencies via bower I get these libraries "unaligned".

Answer (score 1):

Try appending the compiled element to the document body with

```
angular.element(document.body).append(element);
```

You can put it in a beforeEach block:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
    var compile, element, rootScope, scope;
    compile = _$compile_;
    rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    scope = rootScope;
    element = angular.element('<hello-directive></hello-directive>');
    compile(element)(scope);
    angular.element(document.body).append(element);
    scope.$apply();
  });
});
```

Comment: no, that's not the problem, the element should contains the rendered directive independently by where the node is located! (anyway I already inject the tag into the dom)... I think that the problem is not in the test suite but rather related to the test environment (maybe some kind of "conflict"/"race condition" of plugins)